# Install Ubuntu (and windows) to Macbook 2.1 (late 2006)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, macbook

I have a [Macbook 2.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP18?locale=en_US) "late 2006" and for a couple of years I've been using the next (rare) setup of Operating Systems:

- Partition 1: MAC OS X (Snow Leopard)
- Partition 2: Windows Vista and Ubuntu by means of WUBI

I mainly use Ubuntu and in some cases Windows due to some software that is not compatible with Linux. MAC OS X is completely useless for me, and I had problems during an update that prevents me now to boot with MAC OS X.

I have purchased a SSD. I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 but WUBI is not officially supported anymore and I prefer a clean install.

I would like to know if it is possible to install Ubuntu (erasing completely MAC OS X) and if afterwards I could create a partition and install Windows there.

In addition, I have seen that there is some [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook2-1) in order to install different versions of Ubuntu in Macbooks, but its seems that there are not much up to date. Is Macbook 2.1 fully suported in 14.04?